# Notice: Undefined variable: conn, Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in, Fatal error: Uncaught Error

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

tengo unos errores cuando envio los datos de mi registro estos son los errores:

> Error: INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,telefono,correo,direccion) values ('1s','dd','1212','s12','ds@gmail.com','ss','dd')
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

y este el el codigo gracias ;)

```
<?php 

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "clini";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<?php 
  
$name = $_POST['name'];
 $last = $_POST['apellido'];
 $user = $_POST['username'];
 $iden = $_POST['ci'];
 $phone = $_POST['te'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $address = $_POST['dire'];
 $contra = $_POST['pass']; 
 
 $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $_POST['name']);
 
 if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,telefono,correo,direccion)
    values ('$user','$contra','$iden','$phone','$email','$address','$contra')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='index.html' </script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Pues te dice que la variable $conn no esta definida, tienes que definirla

Comment: Hola lo actualize y ahora me sale este error **Error: INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,telefono,correo,direccion) values ('1s','dd','1212','s12','ds@gmail.com','ss','dd')
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1** _ACTUALIZE EL CODIGO_

Comment: Tienes mas columnas que valores, cuentalas tienes 8 columnas y 7 valores

Comment: Listo muchas gracias!